# Delete a managed release package

Tags: apex, managed-package, delete

I have few questions regarding managed release packages:

- Can you delete a managed release package if it is not installed in any subscriber org?
- After deletion of managed release package, can you re-upload the package as a new release package from the same or different org?
- Can I have multiple managed release packages for the same code base in different orgs? Would that cause any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you delete a managed release package if it is not installed in any subscriber org?

Yes, if you can get it uninstalled from all subscriber orgs (including any sandboxes, etc), you can delete the package entirely. I've personally done this in one of my developer orgs a while ago.

> After deletion of managed release package, can you re-upload the package as a new release package from the same or different org?

You can create a new package and select that as your new managed package. You cannot migrate your namespace to a different developer org, so you're stuck with the org you have, unless you want to create a new namespace.

> Can I have multiple managed release packages for the same code base in different orgs? Would that cause any problems?

No, a namespace can only be uploaded from one org, and cannot be removed or migrated to a new org. As such, you can't have multiple releases in different orgs. All releases must be in the same org. You can upload as many versions as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks so much. Would the deletion of the package require a request to be raised with the salesforce support?

Comment: @Brian It's been a while, so I honestly don't remember, but I managed to get it done in my personal dev org, which has neither Partner Support or Premier Support. I think you're allowed so long as there's no installs of your package, but you'll want to experiment. Just go ahead and try. Worst case scenario is the system will tell you to contact support. Just make sure you're willing to commit to the deletion, because it is irreversible.

Comment: I see. I have created a temporary org with a diff namespace for my managed package and am planning to upload it as a release package and then delete it. I have a different packaging org for the final managed package. The deletion shouldn't affect the main packaging org in anyway right? It is a different namespace altogether. Sorry being a little paranoid about this since some of these actions are irreversible and I don't want to get stuck going back n forth with the support! :)

Comment: @Brian Yeah, the wording is a bit paranoid, but for an old hat it's just the same old news. Don't worry about it too much. Just make sure you deploy okay in the new org before you delete.

Answer (score 4):

You can contact Salesforce support to request that a managed - released version be reverted to a managed - beta status if it is not installed in any orgs. If you want to rollback a specific version rather than deleting the package entirely this is likely the option you want to take.

This cannot be done if the package version to be rolled back **or any newer version** is installed in any orgs. It must be uninstalled for this to be an option.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it required to contact salesforce support to delete a package or it can be done without them?

Comment: Once you've released versions I don't believe it can be ever fully deleted. If you want to stop further installs of the package you can deprecated the versions from the packaging area in setup.